Issues with Next/Link with app folder - How can I stop 404'ing?
So here I have a part of my NavBar()
        {/* Desktop Nav */}
        <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-6">
          <Link href={item1Href}>
            <div className="text-lg hover:text-gray-400">{item1}</div>
          </Link>
          <Link href={item2Href}>
            <div className="text-lg hover:text-gray-400">{item2}</div>
          </Link>
          <Link href={item3Href}>
            <div className="text-lg hover:text-gray-400">{item3}</div>
          </Link>
          <Link href={item4Href}>
            <div className="text-lg hover:text-gray-400">{item4}</div>
          </Link>
          <Link href={buttonLink}>
            <button className="border-2 shadow-2xl hover:bg-white 
             hover:text-black transition duration-300 px-8 py-4">
              Residents
            </button>
          </Link>
          <Link href={buttonLink}>
            <button className="border-2 shadow-2xl hover:bg-white 
             hover:text-black transition duration-300 px-8 py-4">
              Apply Now
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>

And here is how im using the component
      <NavBar 
        item1="Amenities" item1Href="/#amenities"
        item2="Floor Plans" item2Href="/#floorplans"
        item3="Directions" item3Href="/#directions"
        item4="Contact Us" item4Href="/contact"
      />

My problem is that {item4Href} which is "/contact" 404's. I figure it's likely because my project is set up like


src

app

contact.js






and not the regular pages folder but Next/Link should understand
const nextConfig = {
    pagesDir: './app',
  }

within next.config.mjs.
Recently - I just tried using the file convention


src

app

contact

contact.js








and I still got a 404

change the name of contact.js file to page.jsx and keep it inside the contact folder

src

contact

page.jsx






try to rename your contact.js with page.jsx or page.jsx

So simple, thank you so much. I was so close haha!
